# Is it legitimate to combine INSERT and SELECT statements in SQL?

Tags: sql

Is it legitimate to use a SELECT and INSERT simultaneously? Suppose we want to move old records from one table to another table with the same columns -- can I do this in a single statement? I feel like it should be possible with a stored procedure and it would be interesting to see how that could be done (from my perspective it would seem easier to manage this sort of thing in a programmatic context.) I'm actually primarily curious about whether it would legitimate to write a statement with both a SELECT from one table and use that information to INSERT into another, and hopefully an example of what that might look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (<column names>) 
SELECT <column names> FROM SourceTable
WHERE blah blah blah...
```

Answer (score 2):

yes...

```
insert into newtable(col1, col2, ...) 
select col1, col2, ... from othertable
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [SELECT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) SQL statement.  Sounds like that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Thank you so much.